# Search for a string and duplicate it with modification in gvim

Tags: linux, vim

I am trying to grep a line, modify it and add a modified copy of the line.

Eg:

```
buffer (Z, A);
```

I want the output to be:

```
buffer (A1, A);
buffer (Z, A1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your example includes only one buffer (the current one), it could be handled with the following `substitute` command:

```
:%s /\(buffer\)(\(\a\),\s*\(\a\))/\1(\31, \2)^M\1(\2, \31)
```

Note that `^M` is the terminal code for `<CR>` (i.e., pressing `Ctrl-V<CR>`, see `:h i_ctrl-v`).

If, however, you want to apply it to multiple files, you could combine `grep`, `cfdo` and `substitute` like so:

```
:silent exe "grep! buffer **/*.*" | :cfdo %s /\(buffer\)(\(\a\),\s\(\a\))/\1(\31, \2)^M\1(\2, \31)
```

There are probably more elegant ways to achieve what you want, but the above commands should at least get the job done.

Comment: I dont think `[:alpha:]` is vim regex is it? `\a` is enough here. This seems a bit more readable to me (but that could be subjective):
`:%s/\vbuffer \((\a), (\a)\);/buffer (A1, \2)\rbuffer (\1, A1)`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I do think it's supported in both vim and neovim. I've tried it in both and also found it in the documentation. That said, saving a few characters of typing doesn't hurt, so I'll accept your suggestion :)

Comment: hmm my bad! `[:alpha:]` does indeed work, but it is a bit strange `[:alpha:]` for a single characters does not work, it must be part of a collection -> `[[:alpha:]]`